# new wordpress design over an existing complicated one?

Tags: wordpress

Hey folks, I got a project from a firm program out a Wordpress design. 80% into it I learn that the client already have an existing one, a robust one, with subsrciptions, blogs, forums, newsletter mailers and so on. Turns out there is a discrepancy bettweent design and old wp structure which I will work on resolving.

I have been developing in on my own server for the time being.

At this point I am not clear on what the strategy should be.

1.) Export out the current wp site out to a different server, duplicate it and then reskin/rework the frame work.

2.) The firms hope was that I would be able to go in and add a new theme, but am not convinced that doing this live will be a good idea since I am using a different theme so all the hooks will be different then the current one.

3.) There is already a large amount of users etc that have signed up to the existing newletter, forum etc. Not sure how to carry this forward?

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely make a copy of the existing environment. Check it into a version control system (if it's not already the case) and work on that.

Try to put all your work into a new theme: That will make installing the changes on the production server super-easy.

Be careful about any notifications and pings that your development copy may send to the outside world. Be especially careful about the newsletter.

Comment: Is this basically the same thing as the post above? Or are we saying develop a new theme then integrate old them. Or Bring in old site and apply new theme?

Comment: @Driftwood it'll depend how deep your changes go. At any rate work on a copy. Then see what you need to do to install the changes on the live site

Comment: I thought by the way that @Freyr's answer was perfectly fine, no idea why he deleted it

Comment: yeah I was looking for it. Here is the plan, I have downloaded the site and the db, 2.2gb db :( Their wordpress site is fully loaded. Will activate locally and see what adding my theme does. My worry is that they have so much stuff I don't know what is relevant and not.

Comment: ok - that did not work. I tried to bring in bits a pieces of the site but the existing site is so complicated and a mess.

Comment: SO I finished the site, turned out great - duplicated the hole thing and brought in the new design and re-hooked it to all the content.